# A reasonable choice of effect size for a meta-analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis, meta-regression, network-meta-analysis, metafor

I'm doing a meta-analysis where the studies ask the study participants to read, find, and correct the wrong words in a text.

Some studies score each study participant's performance on the text using:

**proportion = # of corrected words / all words needing correction**

These studies provide *Mean & SD* for effect size calculation:

```
             Mean     SD    n
 control     0.45     0.17  20
 treatment   0.17     0.11  19
```

Other studies score each study participant's performance on the text using:

**raw_counts = # of corrected words**

These studies provide *Mean & SD* for effect size calculation:

```
             Mean     SD    n
 control     4.5      1.12  17
 treatment   4.7      1.59  18
```

**Question:** Can I calculate *[Standardized Mean Difference](https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_9/9_2_3_2_the_standardized_mean_difference.htm)* effect size across all such studies given that their intent is to measure the same thing?